# How to replicate solr shard in different server

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am running solr in cloud mode and creating a collection by executing below command. The problem is some time it creating replication in same server. Please see the image.

```
./solr create -c COMPANY -n COMPANY -s 2 -rf 2 -d /qual/qtotcos1/configsets/solr/COMPANY/
```

[image]

Is there any way we can specify server/node details while creating Collection or is this the behavior?.

Comment: Those are not really the "same server" - it seems you're running multiple servers on each host (i.e. differeing port numbers)? You should be able to use `createNodeSet` to explicitly tell Solr which nodes to use for the collection. You can use [REPLACENODE](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/cluster-node-management.html#replacenode) to move a replica to another node instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh Could not find command to specify Node while creating collection. can you please provide example/link. I am using Solr v8.2

Comment: See `createNodeSet` parameter on the `CREATECOLLECTION` command: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/collection-management.html#create

Comment: You can use the autoscaling to define cluster policies so that Solr will balance based on rules defined